# Is beeing open a requirement in both of these implications?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am able to show these two implications:

1.
Let $X$ be a topological space, $V \subset U\subset X$, U open. If V is connected in U then V is connected in X.

proof:

If V was not connected in X, then $V=A\cup B$, A,B open in X is a separation. Hence $V=(U\cap A)\cup (U\cap B)$, is a sepearation of V in U.

2.

Let $X$ be a topological space, $V \subset U\subset X$, U open. If V is connected in X then V is connected in U.

Assume that $V=O_1\cup O_2$, where $O_1,O_2$
 is open in U, and a separation of V. $O_1=U_1 \cap U$, $O_2 = U_2\cap U$, and since U is open, this will also be a sepeartion of V in X.

My question is: In the first implication I did not seem to use that U was open, so does this hold whatever U is?

In the second implication I had to use that U was open, however I am not absolutely sure that it is needed, because I am not able to find a counterexample, is there a counterexample here?

Comment: Connectedness is a property if the space itself (i.e. it does not change if we consider the space as a subspace of another space as long as the relative topology is the original topology). Hence, it does not matter if $U $ is open or not.